# Navbar contents not changing

Tags: html

Below is my code.  For some reason when I load the page the navbar shows the contents of "Home".  When I click on the Menu tab every works properly.  But for some reason when I click on the Scheme tab I only get the Home tab contents

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="menu-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu" role="tab" aria-controls="menu" aria-selected="false">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="scheme-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#scheme" role="tab" aria-controls="scheme" aria-selected="false">Scheme</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home tab</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu-tab">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <ul>  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="addItem" type="button">Add Item to Menu</button>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addItemInput" placeholder="Enter New Item Here" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    <ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>
                </ul>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scheme" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scheme-tab">What?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I feel like it must be something really simple, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, and should work. I suspect there is an issue with how you are loading your jQuery and Bootstrap JS and CSS files. Check the console to see if there are any errors.

Here is a working sample of your code - where I am simply using the latest jQuery & Bootstrap CDN files:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="menu-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu" role="tab" aria-controls="menu" aria-selected="false">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="scheme-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#scheme" role="tab" aria-controls="scheme" aria-selected="false">Scheme</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home tab</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu-tab">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <ul>
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="addItem" type="button">Add Item to Menu</button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addItemInput" placeholder="Enter New Item Here" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scheme" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scheme-tab">What?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```